# Google Maps API v3.9: Blurry custom markers when zooming

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, customization, blurry

So it appears that Google have fixed the blurry map issue with the 3.9 / 3.10 API, which is great.

But there's a new one with custom markers. As soon as you zoom in one level, the custom markers become corrupted / blurry. They rectify themselves if zooming out, although the process of zooming out also makes the markers slightly blurry.

The 3.8 API does not exhibit this problem with custom markers. Here's a picture illustrating the problem (I suggest you open the image in a new tab; the blurriness isn't as easily visible when the image is scaled to fit this post). The blurring is most noticeable with the straight lines of the paper crane marker:

[image: google maps marker api problem]

I've had a prod through the HTML, but I can't really tell how the markers are placed on the map. But I thought that I'd put this issue out there for anyone who has experienced similar, or if anyone has any thoughts on how this can be resolved, save waiting to see if it's a glitch in the API.

I'm using Chrome 24.0.1312.5 beta-m on Windows and Mac and the problem is exhibited in both. It does not happen in Firefox 16.0.2 or Safari 6. Given that Safari doesn't have this problem, I would then wonder if it's a Chrome-specific issue. I should check to see if it occurs with the non-beta version.

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  Might want to file it at http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/

Comment: How are you drawing these custom markers?  Are they google.maps.Marker objects or pulled in from a KML Overlay?

Comment: @bamnet - they're written using google.maps.Marker objects, using code as created by the awesome http://powerhut.co.uk/googlemaps/custom_markers.php .

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a retina icon instead like this, maybe it works:

```
new google.maps.MarkerImage('icon.png', null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(32,32))
```

The image is actual a 64x64 image but I am using it as a 32x32 image to get the better pixel density.